# How to achieve that one method is always called in every class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I guess this is very basic: I have a ViewController. In this ViewController I have a method called `- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {` etc. I just added another viewController to my app (called TabsEdit) and I would like that the keyboardWillShow method also applies to textfields in this TabsEdit class the same way it does in my ViewController.

Right now, it doesn't. I.e. if I edit a textField in my ViewController, I get all the nice things I told the keyboardWillShow method to do. If I edit a textField in my TabsEdit class, however, I will not get the keyboardWillShow method. I guess I could simply copy it into by TabsEdit.h, but that wouldn't be really good, I suppose. I defined it once, so that should be enough.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class having keyboardWillShow method, derived from UIViewController, have your two other view controllers derive from this class. QED.